# Probability of choosing

Tags: probability

A student must choose one of the subjects, art, geology, or psychology, as an
elective. She is equally likely to choose art or psychology and twice as likely
to choose geology. What are the respective probabilities that she chooses art,
geology, and psychology?

My answers for each are Art= 1/6, Geo= 2/3, Psych=1/6

I realize that this answer has already been solved; however that have different answers. I want to know if my answer is still correct.
To achieve my answer I used the fact that if there was no biased then each subject had a 1/3 chance of being picked, but since the question states that Geo is twice as likely, then Geo becomes 2/3 where Art and Psych become 1/6
and when added up (1/3)+(1/3)+(2/3) it yields 1, which indicates to me that it is correct.

The answer that I found online has 1/4 1/4 and 1/2. Just want to make sure that my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Ask yourself: for the answer you gave, is geology twice as likely as art?

Answer (score 0):

In your solution she is $\dfrac {\frac 23}{\frac 16}=4$ times as likely to choose geology as either one of the other two.  When you doubled geology can halved the others, you created that ratio $4$ because there are two factors of two.